# Why are email addresses being converted automatically into links in my Rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

A string email address is showing up as a link in the view. I do not want the email to show up as a link. Is there a shortcut method that I can use to inside of embedded ruby?

*Edit* The view is being used to send out an email. The email link shows up in the email inbox, not the browser.

Thanks in advance!

@shared_email_address has a string email address attached to the variable. It's being displayed as a link in the view. How do I prevent this?

Here's the line of code:

<%= @client.name %> has just shared with <%= @shared_email_address%>.

Comment: If you look at the raw HTML that is generated from the view is there a mailto: link in there, or is your browser being helpful?

Comment: The view is being used to send out an email. I should have mentioned that before. The email link shows up in the email inbox, not the browser.

Comment: Ahh So in this case the answer is you don't, since the email client is being helpful and making anything that looks like an email address into a link. It is mail client dependent(My copy of mutt doesn't do it). Are you sending multi-part emails, since some clients will not do the auto format stuff in the plain text part, only the html part.